# restriction a non compact operator to compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, compact-operators

If  $T\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is not compact can the restriction of $T$ to an infinite dimensional subspace of $X$ be compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, take any operator $T$ with infinite dimensional kernel, then $T|_{\ker T}=0$ is compact.

More smart example. Take any infinite dimensional Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$. Let $S\in\mathcal{K}(X)$, then restriction of $T:=S\oplus_\infty 1_Y\in\mathcal{B}(X\oplus_\infty Y)$ to $X$ is $S$ which is compact by construction.

Comment: notice $T$ given.

Comment: @sima, then you must formulate you question properly

Answer (score 0):

What the OP probably has is mind, is the question under which circumstances, for a given operator $T\colon X\to Y$ one can find a subspace of $X_0$ of $X$ which is infinite-dimensional and on which $T$ is compact.

This is true for operators which are not bounded below on finite-codimensional subspaces of $X$ (in other words, for operators $T$ which are not [upper semi-Fredholm](http://planetmath.org/semifredholmoperator)). In this case we have Kato's lemma which asserts that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ you will find a basic sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $X$ so that $T$ restricted to $X_0:=\overline{{\rm span}}\{x_n\colon n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is compact and $\|T|_{X_0}\|\leqslant \varepsilon$.

This fact is necessary to prove that sum of two [strictly singular operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_singular_operator) is again strictly singular.